# Implementing 2 phase commit (2pc) with solidity

Tags: solidity

Are there some patterns or some way to implement 2 phase commit with solidity?

Something similar to multi signatures and a fail safe mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick-and-dirty proof of concept code withouth any specific recovery mechanism. The contract acts as the coordinator of the two-phase commit protocol, where users can signal their consent by calling the `commitRequest()` function with a `true` flag. If no user voted for abort then the contract can commit, otherwise abort. Hope this helps!

```
contract Coordinator {
  uint256 public endOfCommitRequest;

  uint256 public commitCounter;
  uint256 public abortCounter;

  constructor(
    uint256 _endOfCommitRequest
  ) public {
   endOfCommitRequest = _endOfCommitRequest;
  }

  function commitRequest(bool agreement) public onlyBeforeEndOfCommitRequest {
    if(agreement) {
        commitCounter++;
    } else {
        abortCounter++;
    }  
  }

  function commit() public onlyAfterCommitPhase {
    if(abortCounter == 0) {
        // commit
    }  else {
        // abort 
    }
  }

  modifier onlyBeforeEndOfCommitRequest() {
    require(now < endOfCommitRequest);  
    _;  
  }

  modifier onlyAfterCommitPhase() {
    require(now > endOfCommitRequest);  
    _;  
  }
}
```

Would be interesting to hear what kind of fail safe mechanism you have in mind! ;)